# Copy Data from One Google sheets Workbook Sheet to another Workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So very much piecing together and learning google scripts and 1st challenge is to do the following:
Several subsheets completed by agents who will use a script to collate onto a master sheet any that are not already on there.

Script will need to:
Check if data in the subsheet table has been been already copied to master sheet (look at a cell for a 0 or 1).
If 0 copy that to the last row of the master sheet. I've used a countifs formula to populate the 0 or 1 on each sub sheet.

I've managed to build the script to do this from one sheet to another in the same workbook but get an error message when trying to do so in different workbooks. Also found a clone script that does copy the data (whole page) to the master but overwrites and not last row and also ignores the 0 and 1 rule.

Looked across many similar questions and online and struggling to see anyone with this same need and fix?

Codes:
Copy all the new data to another sheet in same workbook from the last row:
/**

- Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain Yes
- in the Include column and copies them to the Report sheet.
  */

  function copyRows2() {

  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Import2");

  var tarSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Report");

  var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
  var cell = srcSheet.getRange("C" + i);
  var val = cell.getValue();
  if (val == "0") {

  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i + ":D" + i);

  var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow();
  var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow+1) + ":D" + (tarRow+1));

  srcRange.setValues(tarRange);
  }
  }
  };`

Clone whole Sheet from workbook A to workbook B:

```
function cloneGoogleSheet(ssA, ssB) {



 // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Source Workbook ID');



// source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Import');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Target WorkbookID');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Master2');

  
  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};
```

Update:
have a working code now of:

```
/**
 * Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain Yes
 * in the Include column and copies them to the Report sheet.
 */

function MasterTracker() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("DARS");
  var tSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DOC ID');
  var tarSheet = tSheet.getSheetByName("TrackerPilot");
  var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var cell = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i);
    var val = cell.getValue();
    if (val == "0") {
      
      var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("E" + i + ":U" + i);
      
      var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow();
            var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow+1) + ":Q" + (tarRow+1));
      
      var sourceValues = srcRange.getValues();
      tarRange.setValues(sourceValues);
    }
  }
};
```

But a new problem. On the source sheet there are cells with dropdowns from data validation - even when blank these delay the code when running. Is there an easy way I am missing from Ignoring these rows if the lookup Cell is blank (not a 0 or 1)?

Comment: The openById needs the unique identifier of the file.  You can get that by Google Drive -> Get link and pulling out the mish mash of characters in the link. For example "docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jflaksjflskjfslfjsfja.../edit?usp=sharing"

Comment: Thanks, the openById worked and I have the links in there but just edited them out of the post.

Comment: Are you saying its not working?

Comment: The clone works - taking source data and setting it to the new workbook but not what I need. I need the functionality of the 1st code to copy new data to the last row of the target sheet - but for the target sheet to be on another workbook. Cant seem to get that to work.

Comment: So you are saying a copy of data from workbook to workbook works properly.  But you want a modified version of data from one workbook to the other?

Comment: So - cloning a sheet from workbook 1 to workbook 2 works but overwrites the data on workbook 2 and clones all - regardless of the countif check I put in there. the 1st code copies new data from sheet1 on workbook 1 to sheet2 on workbook 1 but I need that to copy to workbook 2. Thats the bit I cant seem to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to test it but I'm pretty sure it will work.

```
/**
 * Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain Yes
 * in the Include column and copies them to the Report sheet.
 */

function MasterTracker() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("DARS");
  var tSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DOC ID');
  var tarSheet = tSheet.getSheetByName("TrackerPilot");
  var srcData = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();  // get all values
  var sourceValues = [];

  for (var i=1; i<=srcSheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    // i+1 is row number i is index in data array
    // A is column 1 so index is 0 in data array 
    if ( srcData[i][0] === 0 ) {  // assuming the value is a number?
      sourceValues.push(srcData[i].slice(4,21)); // Column E is index 4 and V (Not included) is index 21
    }
  }
  tarSheet.getRange(tarSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,sourceValues.length,sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cloneGoogleSheet(ssA, ssB) {

 // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Source Workbook ID');

// source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Import');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var i = 0;
  var TData = [];
  for( i=0; i<SData.length; i++ ) {
    if( SData[i][2] === 0 ) { // Column C = 0
      TData.push(SData[i]);
    }
  }

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Target WorkbookID');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Master2');

  
  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(1,1,TData.length,TData[0].length).setValues(TData);  // Over write
  // Append ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,TData.length,TData[0].length).setValues(TData);

};
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for putting this together. I am getting Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Is it 0 or "0" in column C?

Comment: It's number 1 if already on the master or 0 if not.

Comment: Have a working code I've added to original post but a new problem. On the source sheet there are cells with dropdowns from data validation - even when blank these delay the code when running. Is there an easy way I am missing from Ignoring these rows if the lookup Cell is blank (not a 0 or 1)?

Comment: You should avoid getValue() setValue() especially in a loop.  Each is a call to the server and affects performance.  You should use getValues() and setValues().  This line is the problem `var val = cell.getValue();`.  Get all your source data and then use and index into the data array.

Comment: Can you advise what code to change and to what? Thanks for help.